# How to get Newtwork status code from FETCH/XHR in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to fetch status code from network FETCH/XHR
[image]

i want to get Status Code: 200 from response , so can i get this using selenium python

i try with

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

# for LOcal 
dpath = os.getcwd()+"/"+'chromedriver'

# create webdriver object
driver = (executable_path=dpath,options=options)

url = "https://pizzaonline.dominos.co.in/cart"
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}


# get geeksforgeeks.org
driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")

# get browser log
logs = driver.get_log("browser")
```

but not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests package within python:

```py
import requests


url = 'your url'
status_code = requests.get(url).status_code
print(status_code) #This will just print the status code of the url

#do your stuff here
```

Comment: This was not work , after the login how can i pass the url

Comment: where is this url coming from?